# Java Inheritance and super keyword

Tags: java

I have been trying to practise some java mcqs and cant get this one
CAN ANYONE EXPLAIN HOW OUTPUT IS -

```
Class A
Class B
Class C
```

and not

```
Class A
Class B
```

```
class A
{
    String s = "Class A";
}
 
class B extends A
{
    String s = "Class B";
 
    {
        System.out.println(super.s);
    }
}
 
class C extends B
{
    String s = "Class C";
 
    {
        System.out.println(super.s);
    }
}
 
public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        C c = new C();
 
        System.out.println(c.s);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the main you have `System.out.println(c.s)`, which will print Class C

Comment: What would you expect as output? Do you want to know why it outputs something you don’t expect?

Comment: Will  super.s in class C refer to class A/B??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

A super-class constructor is always run before the actual constructor of the instance. If there is no explicit call to `super()`, compiler automatically inserts it. Initializer block is "copied" inside the actual constructor.

So `C c = new C();` would print: "Class A Class B", but there is a subsequent line: `System.out.println(c.s);` which prints "Class C"

Answer (score 1):

First we should know that:

**"When there is a hierarchy of inheritance, and we create an *instance of a child*, Parents from the top of the hierarchy get initialized, one after each other (so we get objects created from parents implicitly)."**

So here the order of class objects are getting created from, by calling **new** on class **C** constructor

`C c = new C();`

, would be: ***A ---> B ---> C***

---

Here you've put the **println** statements in **blocks**.
When an object is getting created from a class, blocks get called before the constructor of the Class get executed.
In your code, this would be block in class B

And finally with last line of your code `System.out.println(c.s);`, you've printed the value of `s` attribute of object `c`